# How to make primary key as autoincrement for Room Persistence lib

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I am creating an Entity ([Room Persistence Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room)) class Food, where I want to make `foodId` as autoincrement.

```
@Entity
class Food(var foodName: String, var foodDesc: String, var protein: Double, var carbs: Double, var fat: Double)
{
    @PrimaryKey
    var foodId: Int = 0
    var calories: Double = 0.toDouble()
}
```

How can I set `foodId` an autoincrement field?

Comment: Instead of `0.toDouble()` you can use `0.0` do declare it as a double

Comment: How you create a new instance of Food class? Do you specify manually ID or you leave it blank?

Comment: A note for future readers - the primary key must be 0 for Room to treat it as unset. If you use any other default value (e.g. -1), Room will not autogenerate the id.

Answer (score 560, accepted):

You need to use the `autoGenerate` property

Your primary key annotation should be like this:

```
@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
```

Reference for [PrimaryKey](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/PrimaryKey#autoGenerate()).

Comment: Thanks, i was searching for autoIncrement, thats why wasn't able to find.

Comment: Hey @MatPag what if i want two Primary keys in one table (Composite primary keys) and one of the primary key should be auto incremented? How can i achieve that? Can you answer this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46790830/how-to-make-primary-key-auto-increment-while-using-composite-primary-keys-in-roo) ?

Comment: @MatPeg What in case if I want to have one PrimaryKey the is self-generated, and one that come from REST `@Entity(
    primaryKeys = arrayOf(COLUMN_ID_LOCAL,COLUMN_ID_REMOTE))` ?

Comment: @murt You need a composite primary key, but you can't do what you want to achieve. Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46804610/2910520)

Comment: Important part of the linked documentation: `Insert methods treat 0 as not-set while inserting the item. `

Answer (score 205):

You can add `@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)` like this:

```
@Entity
data class Food(
        var foodName: String, 
        var foodDesc: String, 
        var protein: Double, 
        var carbs: Double, 
        var fat: Double
){
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var foodId: Int = 0 // or foodId: Int? = null
    var calories: Double = 0.toDouble()
}
```

Comment: `foodId` doesn't needs to be null (but it can be). One could also use default values eg. `var foodId: Int = 0` and the autogenerate would work properly.

Comment: That's pretty unintuitive but I can't see how the Room devs could get around it

Comment: What if I want to overwrite foodId - passing it as custom value to Entity?  Does that cause it to not auto-increment?

Comment: @MichałBaran If you make it 0, does it still have to be a null-able int?

Comment: @MichałBaran, from the java doc, when the type is a primitive java ```int``` or ```long```, 0 is treat as null-able, when the type is Integer or Long, null is the  nullable. Since Kotlin Int when non-nullable works in JVM as primitive int, then you are right and ```var foodId: Int = 0``` will work, but ```var foodId: Int? = 0``` will not work since Int? is converted in JVM as Integer. @JMK, if you make it 0, you HAVE to make a non-nullable ```int``` for the reason aforementioned.

Comment: You can write without in another way:
`val jack = User(name = "Jack", phone= 1)`
In this case you can remove 0 from constructor

Comment: The problem I see with this approach is in terms of it being a data class. When Food is a data class (like in the snippet), food is been used for the equals() comparison, so two foods with different foodId can be considered equal.

Using named arguments with default values will solve the issue.

Comment: For me, it was not working when I use Int. But when I set Long instead of Int, it worked.
`@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var foodId: Long = 0`

Comment: @AllanVeloso Can you explain why `foodId` was put in the body and not in the constructor?

Comment: @neer17 since the foodId will be autogenerated by Room at insertion, more likely there will be no use to have it in the constructor.

Comment: My Room database tests failed when the PrimaryKey was defined null. Probably better to make it 0 instead as this seems to properly autogenerate.

Comment: We can add also @Transient, in front of or above "var foodId" in order not to make it serializable when using it with Gson.

Comment: can anyone explain why a primary key would be nullable?!?

Answer (score 71):

add `@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)`

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private int id;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "full_name")
    private String name;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "phone")
    private String phone;

    public User(){
    }

    //type-1
    public User(String name, String phone) {
        this.name = name;
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    //type-2
    public User(int id, String name, String phone) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.phone = phone;
    }

}
```

while storing data

```
 //type-1
 db.userDao().InsertAll(new User(sName,sPhone)); 

 //type-2
 db.userDao().InsertAll(new User(0,sName,sPhone));
```

> type-1
>
> If you are not passing value for primary key, by default it will 0 or
>   null.

type-2

Put **null or zero for the id** while creating object (my case user object)

If the field type is long or int (or its TypeConverter converts it to a long or int), Insert methods treat 0 as not-set while inserting the item.

If the field's type is Integer or Long (Object) (or its TypeConverter converts it to an Integer or a Long), Insert methods treat null as not-set while inserting the item.

Comment: Can we pass custom id to Entity, even though it is set to autoGenerate?

Comment: @Igor Ganapolsky     Yes, but entry will genrate with that custom id [ auto-increment will not work ]
And if you pass same id again it will throw exception 'UNIQUE constraint failed'
so you need pass always new id or make it [0 or null] and let auto-increment do this work for you.

Comment: Why are you even letting the user put the id in the constructor if you want to autogenerate?

Comment: In Kotlin you can use data class and write: 
`val jack = User(name = "Jack", phone= 1)`
In this case you can remove 0 from constructor

Comment: @hellcast If you don't include the id in the constructor (as I just learned the hard way) when you query the DB it won't assign the id field (it will just be whatever you  initialize it with in the constructor) since I assume it calls the same constructor when populating the object's fields.

Comment: why to set the id as 0 even when set to autogenerate??

Answer (score 63):

Its unbelievable after so many answers, but I did it little differently in the end. I don't like primary key to be nullable, I want to have it as first argument and also want to insert without defining it and also it should not be var.

```
@Entity(tableName = "employments")
data class Employment(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) val id: Long,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "code") val code: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "title") val name: String
){
    constructor(code: String, name: String) : this(0, code, name)
}
```

Comment: Now, How you are calling this class Employee without passing id as a parameter? Please tell.

Comment: @JaiminModi you see secondary constructor there ?  yo can call it Employment(code = "code", name = "name") or simple Employment("code", "name")

Comment: Creating an extra constructor isn't even necessary for this case. Just add the 0 as default parameter to the id and you will automatically be able to use the constructor without this extra declaration:

@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) val id: Long = 0L,

Comment: It's not true that you will automatically be able to use the constructor without this extra declaration if you add default value as first parameter. You will have to use named arguments in that case what is mostly not desirable in my case, so that's why secondary constructor is needed here.

Comment: I mean, using named arguments when constructing a class that takes so many Strings, Integers and Longs as parameters is probably the better approach.

Comment: Usually ```@Insert``` annotation in your DAO is marked with conflict resolution strategy which is often ``` ReplaceOnInsert```. When you put existing id in your new row and insert it, id would not be autogenerated, but the row would be replaced.  You also could not leave it as nullable type because you will get runtime exception which claims a db schema requires non-nullable field.

Comment: __UPDATE__: you can leave uid as 0, with zero uid key is autoincremented. Another possible option like -1 would insert it 'as is'

Answer (score 29):

This works for me:

```
@Entity(tableName = "note_table")
data class Note(
    @ColumnInfo(name="title") var title: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name="description") var description: String = "",
    @ColumnInfo(name="priority") var priority: Int,
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) var id: Int = 0//last so that we don't have to pass an ID value or named arguments
)
```

Note that the id is last to avoid having to use named arguments when creating the entity, before inserting it into Room. Once it's been added to room, use the id when updating the entity.

Answer (score 10):

```
@Entity(tableName = "user")
data class User(

@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)  var id: Int?,
       var name: String,
       var dob: String,
       var address: String,
       var gender: String
)
{
    constructor():this(null,
        "","","","")
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: There are many answers like "use `@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)`" - does your answer add anything new to this thread?

Comment: yes it adds - it presents how null covers the autogenearted field

Answer (score 9):

For example, if you have a `users` entity you want to store, with fields `(firstname, lastname , email)` and you want autogenerated id, you do this.

```
@Entity(tableName = "users")
data class Users(
   @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
   val id: Long,
   val firstname: String,
   val lastname: String,
   val email: String
)
```

Room will then autogenerate and auto-increment the `id` field.

Comment: Every time we create a new Users object we will need to pass an id field. Can this be avoided?

Comment: Yes, put `@PrimaryKey(autoGenerated = true) val id: Long? = null` outside the constructor, on the body of the class

Comment: @Magritte Care to elaborate more pls?

Comment: @Ispam In my answer above I posted how the complete class should look like.

Comment: Actually, you can simply put 0 as ID. Room will automatically generate a ID if you have set the @PrimaryKey option.

Comment: Leaving primary key as a null ```val id: Long? = null``` will give you a runtime error with error message claims a db schema requires non-null field. It is on the latest Android API.

Answer (score 5):

In the example below when you create a new user pass the parameters as is in the constructor. Room will autogenerate the id. All user object ids are already set to the int default in the id setter so don't call setId

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private int id;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "full_name")
    private String name;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "phone")
    private String phone;

   
    public User(String name, String phone) {
        this.name = name;
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public void setId(int id){
        this.id = id;
    }

}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

Annotate your Entity class with the code below.

In Java:

```
@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
private int id;
```

In Kotlin:

```
@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
var id: Int
```

Room will then auto-generate and auto-increment the id field.