# Cannot find setter for field - using Kotlin with Room database

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I'm integrating with the Room persistence library. I have a data class in Kotlin like:

```
@Entity(tableName = "story")
data class Story (
        @PrimaryKey val id: Long,
        val by: String,
        val descendants: Int,
        val score: Int,
        val time: Long,
        val title: String,
        val type: String,
        val url: String
)
```

The `@Entity` and `@PrimaryKey` annotations are for the Room library. When I try to build, it is failing with error:

```
Error:Cannot find setter for field.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

I also tried providing a default constructor:

```
@Entity(tableName = "story")
data class Story (
        @PrimaryKey val id: Long,
        val by: String,
        val descendants: Int,
        val score: Int,
        val time: Long,
        val title: String,
        val type: String,
        val url: String
) {
    constructor() : this(0, "", 0, 0, 0, "", "", "")
}
```

But this doesn't work as well. A thing to note is that it works if I convert this Kotlin class into a Java class with getters and setters. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: In https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/master/BasicRxJavaSampleKotlin/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/observability/persistence/User.kt from google's example, immutable properties works without any problem. Can someone analyze the cause? Could it be a bug?

Answer (score 242, accepted):

Since your fields are marked with `val`, they are effectively final and don't have setter fields.

Try switching out the `val` with `var`.
You might also need to initialize the fields.

```
@Entity(tableName = "story")
data class Story (
        @PrimaryKey var id: Long? = null,
        var by: String = "",
        var descendants: Int = 0,
        var score: Int = 0,
        var time: Long = 0L,
        var title: String = "",
        var type: String = "",
        var url: String = ""
)
```

**EDIT**

The above solution is a general fix for this error in Kotlin when using Kotlin with other Java libraries like Hibernate where i've seen this as well. If you want to keep immutability with Room, see some of the other answers which may be more specific to your case.

In some cases immutability with Java libraries is simply not working at all and while making sad developer noises, you have to switch that `val` for a `var` unfortunately.

Comment: Hey I figured something weird about this, Could you have a look at it? https://stackoverflow.com/q/47323883/4620609

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, this issue killed around 2hrs for me.....I used "private var" and it was throwing error, had no clue

Comment: The answer means 'don't use Room, it forces you to write bad code', right?

Comment: Please beware that var usage in data class leads to effective immutability loss.

Comment: This solution worked for me, but for anyone else having the same issue. I also had to remove my private visibility modifier.

Comment: No need to make all the fields read/write. Just changing the primary key fixed the issue

Comment: Sometimes we design for our entity to be `val` immutable instead of using `var`. Please check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56126801/3763032) for this fix, when you prefer to use `val` over `var`

Comment: This is not necessary. In my case the error was caused by using the @Ignore annotation on one of the fields. Of course Room doesn't know what to insert there when creating the object from the database.

Comment: The why isn't clear

Answer (score 60):

Hey I don't know if everyone know or not, but you can not have column which is starting from `is` into `Room`. 
For example you can't have like this

```
   @Entity(tableName = "user")
   data class User (
        @PrimaryKey var id: Long? = null,
        var userName: String = "",
        var isConnectedToFB: Boolean = false,
)
```

Comment: For my case, the "is" prefix don't work for field name.

But "is" prefix works with Boolean type field.

Comment: @AlexAndro I gave example in kotlin itself can you please explain what is not working ?

Comment: @AJay I mean I agree you that in `kotlin` you can not have such fields. (up vote) Anyway, in `java` I noticed is permitted.

Comment: @AlexAndro oh okay

Comment: The same thing happens in Java. You can not use "mIs___" or "is____" . It will cause the same error. Hungarian notation will not save you.

Comment: Working in kotlin

Comment: `ColumnName` doesn't matter if it is not started with `is`. Only works with renaming of var

Comment: I also solved my issue using this answer. I was using ``new`` for filed name. Then changed it to newCall and it worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: That's right. the field name should not start with "is" when it is boolean type.

Comment: Where's the docs for this please?

Comment: Can't thank you enough for this solution. Was stuck for almost a day thinking why my code wasn't working when it was logically perfect.

Answer (score 15):

If you have `@Ignore` field in the data class constructor you need to move it to class body like this:

```
@Entity(primaryKeys = ["id"])
data class User(
        @field:SerializedName("id")
        val id: Int,

        @field:SerializedName("name")
        val name: String,
    
        @field:SerializedName("age")
        val age: Int
) {
    @Ignore
    val testme: String?
}
```

All kudos go to [marianperca](https://github.com/marianperca) on GitHub: https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/issues/421#issuecomment-442763610

Answer (score 11):

There is an issue in room db library java code generation.

I was using optional field `isFavorite`. It gives me same error then I change my field name to `favorite` then compiled.

before
`var isFavorite: Int? = 0,`

after changing working fine
`var favorite: Int? = 0,`

Thanks

Comment: Change your data type. I have same field named isFavourite in my db I changed my field type to boolean and now it's worked for me.

@ColumnInfo(name = "is_favourite")
 var isFavourite: Boolean = false

Answer (score 11):

Just make the variables mutable, change `val` into `var` for Kotlin, Or private into public for Java

Answer (score 9):

Had this error in Java.

You cannot have a column starting with `is` or `is_` in Java.

Try renaming the column.

Another solution:

You either have to pass the field in the constructor and initialize it with the constructor argument, or create a setter for it.

Example:

```
public MyEntity(String name, ...) {
   this.name = name;
   ...
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/46753804/2914140 if you have an autogenerated primary key, you should write so:

```
@Entity(tableName = "story")
data class Story (
        val by: String,
        val descendants: Int,
        val score: Int,
        val time: Long,
        val title: String,
        val type: String,
        val url: String
)  {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var id: Int = 0
}
```

Note that `@PrimaryKey` is written inside the class body and contains modifier `var`.

If you later want to update a row in a database with different parameters, use these lines:

```
val newStory = story.copy(by = "new author", title = "new title") // Cannot use "id" in object cloning
newStory.id = story.id
dao.update(newStory)
```

UPDATE

I still don't use AndroidX, and Room is 'android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.1.1'.

You can extend this class from `Serializable`. But if you want to extend it from `Parcelable`, you will get a warning (over `id` variable): `Property would not be serialized inro a 'Parcel'. Add '@IgnoredOnParcel' annotation to remove this warning`:

[image]

Then I moved an `id` from the body to the constructor. In Kotlin I use `@Parcelize` to create `Parcelable` classes:

```
@Parcelize
@Entity(tableName = "story")
data class Story (
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var id: Int = 0,

    val by: String,
    val descendants: Int,
    val score: Int,
    val time: Long,
    val title: String,
    val type: String,
    val url: String
) : Parcelable
```

Comment: If you do this, you will likely want to override `equals` and `hashcode`.

Comment: @Tenfour04, but why? They are generated in `data class` automatically. But I didn't compare two objects.

Comment: They are only generated for constructor properties. Since you moved the primary key outside the constructor, the `id` is no longer included in the auto-generated `equals` and `hashcode` which would be surprising behavior.

Comment: @Tenfour04, agree with you, thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 6):

This error will be thrown if your column starts with Is:

```
@ColumnInfo(name = "IsHandicapLeague")
    @NonNull
    var isHandicapLeague: String = "Y"
```

Add a default set() function to eliminate

```
fun setIsHandicapLeague(flag:String) {
    isHandicapLeague = flag
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The correct way to fix this issue would be simply updating to **Room v2.4.3 or higher**.

### Workaround

If you're running on an older version of Room, one that uses an old version of the `kotlinx-metadata-jvm` library which doesn't understand 1.5.x metadata, a simple workaround would be adding the following line to your `build.gradle`:

```
kapt "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-metadata-jvm:0.5.0"
```

Source: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-45883/KAPT-Cannot-find-setter-for-field-compiling-projects-with-Room-db-breaks-using-150-M2

Answer (score 4):

This is a bug and is fixed in Room `2.1.0-alpha01`

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/release-notes#october_8_2018

> Bug Fixes
>
> - Room will now properly use Kotlin’s primary constructor in
>     data classes avoiding the need to declare the fields as vars.
>     [b/105769985](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/105769985)

Comment: I'm using `2.1.0-alpha03` but I still get this error

Comment: Same in 2.1.0-alpha04

Comment: Tried with 2.5.0-beta01 and looks like this fixed the error.

Answer (score 4):

I've found that another cause of this compilation error can be due to the use of the Room's `@Ignore` annotation on fields of your entity data class:

```
@Entity(tableName = "foo")
data class Foo(

    // Okay
    @PrimaryKey
    val id: String,

    // Okay
    val bar: String,

    // Annotation causes compilation error, all fields of data class report
    // the "Cannot find setter for field" error when Ignore is present
    @Ignore
    val causeserror: String
)
```

The same error also seems to happens when using the `@Transient` annotation.

I've noticed this issue using version `2.2.2` of Room:

```
// build.gradle file
dependencies {
   ...
   kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.2.2"
   ...
}
```

Hope that helps someone!

Comment: Did you find any solution for this? Stuck with same case. Thanks

Comment: In my case , I needed to remove `@Ignore` from fields on my entity class. Perhaps you have `@Ignore` included on fields on one or more of your entity classes?

Comment: Obviously, Room library cannot instantiate an object of your data class, because data class must have a field that does not exist in the database (because of the `@Ignore` annotation).

Answer (score 4):

Updating Room library to the latest version [2.4.2](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/room#2.4.2) solve the issue

Comment: Problems still exist even after my upgrading room to 2.4.2

Comment: Tried with 2.5.0-beta01 and looks like this fixed the error.

Answer (score 3):

You can try to rename id variable to another name. It worked for me ;

```
var id: Long? = null
```

to

```
var workerId: Long? = null
```

If you have to name as id and you are using retrofit, then you may need to add SerializedName("id")

Answer (score 3):

It seems like Room and Kotlin versions need to be matched. I have same issue with `Room 2.3.0` and `Kotlin 1.6.10` but it's ok with Kotlin `1.5.20`. It looks ok after I updated `Room` to `2.4.2`.
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-45883

Also [there is](https://coroutinedispatcher.com/posts/solving-room-cannot-find-setter-for) a possible solution to use `@JvmOverloads constructor` for better Java compability.

Answer (score 2):

Another cause of this may be the naming of the field. If you use any of the pre-defined keywords, you will get the same error. 
For instance, you can not name your column "is_active".

Reference: http://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html

Answer (score 1):

Just an update if somebody comes across this thread in 2019, after spending hours digging online on why this should work, but it doesn't.

Using `val` works as expected if you are using the AndroidX version ( `androidx.room:room-<any>:2.*`) but it doesn't when using the old `android.arch.persistence.room:<any>:1.1.1` and it seems that version `2.*` wasn't released on this latter repo.

Edit: typos

Comment: Yes, AndroidX will replace support libraries, so Room will never be 2.0 on old `android.arch.persistence.room`.

Comment: Thanks for the info

Comment: val doesn't work in my case with Int and Long even with androidx and newest Room

Answer (score 1):

If you want the `val` immutability available for your entity, it is possible.

1. You should update to AndroidX room [current version](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/room).
2. Check for the related [issue here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/69539767) it is marked as **Won't Fix**
3. Now they have release a fix related to the issue with [version 2.0.0-beta01](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/room#2.0.0-beta01)
4. Now you can use immutable `val` with `default value` e.g:

```
@Entity("tbl_abc")
data class Abc(
    @PrimaryKey
    val id: Int = 0, 
    val isFavourite: Boolean = false
)
```

Previously, the above snippet will throw an error of `Cannot find setter for field`. Changing into `var` is a great workaround, but I prefer for the entity class to be immutable from outside invocation

Answer (score 0):

You can now start your field with `is` but you can't have a number next to the `is` like : `is2FooSelected`, you have to rename to `isTwoFooSelected`.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the variable we wrote as id is getting mixed up with the id in the system. Therefore, when I define it as uuid, my error is resolved. I think it will be solved too. Also, try using var instead of val.

@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
var uuid:Int=0

Answer (score -2):

Just use var instead of val and if you are using private keyword, make it public.

```
@Entity(tableName = "story")
data class Story (
        @PrimaryKey val id: Long,
        var by: String,
        var descendants: Int,
        var score: Int,
        var time: Long,
        var title: String,
        var type: String,
        var url: String
)
```

Comment: consider immutability