# Why Room entities don't work with immutable properties in Android

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin, immutability, android-room

I have been exploring [Room](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/index.html) database object mapping library and I figured something weird.

An entity data model cannot have immutable properties, as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44213583/4620609) answer suggests.

But I checked out [google's persistent example with kotlin](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/tree/master/BasicRxJavaSampleKotlin), `Room` works with immutable properties too. Please check [this](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/master/BasicRxJavaSampleKotlin/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/observability/persistence/User.kt) data class from the example.

What could be the reason for this behavior?

This could be a good feature if we could create immutable values (`val` properties), as this restrict programmers from changing unique identifiers such as ids after an object has been created.

Comment: I'm not an expert on Room specifically, but I believe if you want to use `val`, you need to give default values for everything since it might be relying on a default constructor or something unless this has changed recently. Also, you won't be able to change values once they are set.

Comment: @JanVladimirMostert Thanks for the reply. I did test that with default values, still the problem seem to occur

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's weird because I can make my Entity class using `val` for all of my fields without an issue

```
@Entity(tableName = "repo")
data class RepoEntity(
        @PrimaryKey @ColumnInfo(name = "id") @SerializedName("id") val id: Int,
        @ColumnInfo(name = "name") @SerializedName("name") val name: String,
        @ColumnInfo(name = "full_name") @SerializedName("full_name") val fullName: String,
        @Embedded(prefix = "owner") @SerializedName("owner") val owner: RepoOwnerEntity,
        @ColumnInfo(name = "html_url") @SerializedName("html_url") val htmlUrl: String,
        @ColumnInfo(name = "description") @SerializedName("description") val description: String?
)
```

And the data still stored correctly inside the Database.
[image]

Comment: Could you post your gradle files? Both project level and module level?

Comment: You can check all the code on my github repo > https://github.com/RR12/KU-Android-Project-Setup all the db related stuff should be on `data` module.

Comment: This isn't possible , i have the same issue too

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the issue stems from certain fields which can not be constructor parameters. From the Javadoc of the `@Relation` annotation:

> Note that the `@Relation` annotated field cannot be a constructor parameter, it must be public or have a public setter.

As a workaround, I had a private constructor parameter `_myRelationProperty` and a public field:

```
val myRelationProperty: List<MyThings> get() = _myRelationProperty
```