# How to make composite key in Room

Tags: android, android-room

I have just found @PrimaryKey annotation in room. So If I want to make composite key so how can I do that?

Comment: What does a composite primary key have to do with MVVM?

Comment: Yes CommonsWare these both are independent. Thanks for pointing it out, I'll modify my question.

Answer (score 131, accepted):

Make use of `primaryKeys()`.

[Android Developer Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/PrimaryKey.html) for `Room` states:

> If PrimaryKey annotation is used on a Embeddedd field, all columns
> inherited from that embedded field becomes the composite primary key
> (including its grand children fields).

Example implementation in Java:

```java
@Entity(primaryKeys = {"column1","column2","column3"})
public class DummyClass {
    ...
}
```

Example implementation in kotlin:

```kotlin
@Entity(primaryKeys = ["column1","column2","column3"])
class DummyClass {
    ...
}
```

Thanks [Lalit Kushwah](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4788592/lalit-kushwah) for the example.

Comment: Thanks It worked, Here I am sharing the implementation in case if anyone requires:  

@Entity (primaryKeys = {"column1","column2"})

Comment: Is this the example of creating a composite primary key ??

Comment: yes this one is example of creating composite primary key

Answer (score 32):

Here is an example for Kotlin:

```
import android.arch.persistence.room.Entity

@Entity(primaryKeys= [ "first_name", "last_name" ] )
class User{
    .......
}
```

Comment: How to make one of them as `autogenerate = true`?

Comment: @WahibUlHaq https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46790830/how-to-make-primary-key-auto-increment-while-using-composite-primary-keys-in-roo that might answer your question

Comment: Use '{' instead of '['

Comment: I think for java you need `{` and for kotlin you need `[`

Answer (score 9):

This worked for me I'm using Kotlin 1.3, I think.

```
@Entity(tableName = "location_table", primaryKeys = ["lat", "lon"])
    data class MyLocation(
    //    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) var id: Long?,
        var lat: Double,
        var lon: Double,
        var dateTime: String,
        var weatherDescription: String,
        var temperature: Double
    )
```

Answer (score 4):

You can declare an entity on top of your existing entity class such as following

```
@Entity
 (tableName = "Equipment_History", primaryKeys = {"EquipName","EquipFunctionalLocation"})
public class EquipmentHistory {

    @ColumnInfo @NonNull
    private String EquipFunctionalLocation;
    @ColumnInfo @NonNull
    private String EquipName;
//rest of the columns 

}
```

In this way you can have the table name of your own choice and also can declare a composite primary key in room but make sure you add the @NonNull annotation alongside your @ColumnInfo annotation otherwise the code won't work, because room will give you a compile-time error otherwise as stated on the google developers website.
Hope, this will help.