# Primary key does not exist in the entity in android room with composite key

Tags: android, database, primary-key, android-room, composite-primary-key

The error I am getting is:

> error: theme_id, picture_id referenced in the primary key does not exists in the Entity. Available column names:theme_id, picture_id, image

I have looked extensively online but i cannot find anything about this.
This error only seemst to pop uw when trying to use the composite key.
If I annotate one of the fields with a normal PrimaryKey it works just fine.
I do not understand what is going on here and it is frustrating that i cannot find anything online about this.
I hope you guys will be able to help me.

Entity

```
@Entity(primaryKeys = {"theme_id, picture_id"}, tableName = "picture")
public class Picture {

    @ColumnInfo(name = "theme_id")
    private int themeId;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "picture_id")
    private int pictureId;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "image", typeAffinity = ColumnInfo.BLOB)
    private byte[] image;
}
```

Dao

```
@Dao
public interface PictureDao {

    @Insert
    void instertPictures(Picture... pictures);

    @Update
    void updatePictures(Picture... pictures);

    @Delete
    void deletePictures(Picture... pictures);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM picture")
    List<Picture> getAllPictures();

    @Query("SELECT * FROM picture WHERE theme_id = :themeId")
    List<Picture> getThemePictures(int themeId);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM picture WHERE theme_id = :themeId AND picture_id = :pictureId")
    Picture getPicture(int themeId, int pictureId);

}
```

Database

```
@Database(entities = {Picture.class}, version = 1, exportSchema = false)
public abstract class PictureDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

    public static final String NAME = "picture_db";

    public abstract PictureDao pictureDao();
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make composite key in Room while using MVVM in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47130307/how-to-make-composite-key-in-room-while-using-mvvm-in-android)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You get this error, because you haven't created column named `theme_id, picture_id`. Probably you meant to have 2 primary keys `theme_id` and `picture_id`. Then you have to pass two strings separated with comma, not one with comma inside.

So change

```
{"theme_id, picture_id"}
```

```
 "  only one string   "
```

to

```
{"theme_id", "picture_id"}
```

```
 " first  ", "  second  "
 " string "  "  string  "
```

and it should work just fine.

Comment: Hey thanks a ton for you answer. I don't know how I overlooked this.

Comment: Just want to say that I havent actually tested your fix. I just suppose it will work. I got it to work with public staic final int fields in there. but Its the same solution actually.