# Can i make non-primary key field as autogenerated value in room

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room, android-database

I have table with composite primary key. Can I make one of the filed as auto generated.

Secenario : 
I have a `teacher table` containing the fields techerId, name, gender, role, department, grade and it has composite primary id which consist of role, department and grade. How to make teacherid as auto-generated ?

Comment: check here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/46804610/10511266

Comment: @Rakki you tried the answer?

Comment: ya i tried its worked

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you go through [THIS ANSWER](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46804610/7976274), you will find that we can't have auto increment property in Composite Primary keys. So, the workaround would be to use concept of `indexing` and `unique constraint`. Make the `role`,`deptt`,`grade` columns as you `indices` and set the `unique` constraint as `true`. This will ensure that the pair of these three values are always unique(like primaryKey). Then add the `techerId` as `Primarykey`(autoGenerate = true) in the entity. Your `entity` class would look something like:

```
@Entity(tableName = "teacher",indices = arrayOf(Index(value = ["role","department","grade"],unique = true)))
public class Teacher{
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    int teacher_id;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "name")
    String teacher_name;

    //Rest of the fields
    ......
    ......
}
```