# How to set the starting value for an auto increment primary key in a Room database

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-room

I'm trying to set my id field start to increment from 2018

```
@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
   @ColumnInfo(name = "id")
   private int id = 2018;
```

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44109700/how-to-make-primary-key-as-autoincrement-for-room-persistence-lib)

Comment: Why? If you think that this will represent a year, SQLite can use whatever primary key values that it wants to assign. If you want particular values for the key, do not auto-generate the key, but instead use values that you specify.

Comment: i want my user to remember their id easily @CommonsWare

Comment: Then assign a primary key yourself, and do not use auto-generate. SQLite does not guarantee that auto-generated primary keys are easy to remember.

Comment: @CommonsWare I get your point but not having possibility to at least exclude some values from autogenerated values is not cool. One of problems I see is that the very 1st entity to be created gets 0 - 0 sounds like some error value, it might as well come from not properly initialized primitives, see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html.

Comment: @MarianPaździoch: Then assign a primary key yourself, and do not use auto-generate. SQLite does not guarantee that auto-generated primary keys are not going to resemble some error value.