# Coroutine waiting for task in other function with same scope

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, coroutine

I have a function like this that inserts a new row in a table with rowId:

```
@Composable
fun AddNewCustomer() {
    val db = CustomersDatabase.getDatabase(LocalContext.current)
    val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    val createMainEntity = {
        coroutineScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val rowId = db.customersDao().getLast()!!.id + 1
            db.customersDao().insertPrimaries(CustomersEntity(rowId, null, null, null))

        }
    }
    createMainEntity()
    otherFunc(db, coroutineScope)      
    
}
```

and in another function, I insert a new row to another table:

```
@Composable
private fun otherFunc(
    db: CustomersDatabase,
    coroutineScope: CoroutineScope,
) {
        val save = {
                coroutineScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
                    delay(100)
                    val rowId = db.customersDao().getLast()!!.id
                    db.customersDao().insertPhone(PhoneNumberEntity(phone = "", customerId = rowId , field = "" ))
   }
   }
        save()
}
```

I want to save() in `otherFunc` waits till createMainEntity finishes,
with delay, I can be sure the `createMainEntity` finishes first but it's a dirty way how can I do that better.

Comment: You need two suspend functions, one for adding user and otherFunc. And then call them one after another inside launch block of your scope. See: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/composing-suspending-functions.html#sequential-by-default

Comment: Does `AddNewCustomer` or `otherFunct` need to be `@Composable`? They don't look like they create UI to me. Where are you calling each of them from? I barely started reading about Compose, but isn't it critical that Composable functions not create side effects? Otherwise, when the screen gets recomposed, you'll be performing side effects again at an unexpected time.

Comment: @Tenfour04 yes i skipped UI codes

Comment: So where do you call them from?

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I understand about Compose, these functions absolutely should not be Composables. A Composable function must not affect external state because it must be idempotent. You could call one of these functions from a listener lambda in one of your Composables, but you must not call them directly.

Accordingly, the function name should not start with a capital letter by convention. I also added "Async" to the name to signify that it does something asynchronously (by launching a coroutine that runs separately).

To call the other function after the Room transaction is complete, call it inside the coroutine that is performing the transaction.

Also, it is convoluted to create a lambda function solely to immediately call it and do nothing else with it, so I removed that. Your fixed function looks like:

```
fun addNewCustomerAsync(coroutineScope: CoroutineScope) {
    val db = CustomersDatabase.getDatabase(LocalContext.current)
    coroutineScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        val rowId = db.customersDao().getLast()!!.id + 1
        db.customersDao().insertPrimaries(CustomersEntity(rowId, null, null, null))
        createMainEntity() 
        otherFunc(db, coroutineScope) 
    }
}
```

Your other function should simply be a suspend function. A dispatcher doesn't need to be specified because it doesn't call any blocking functions.

```
private suspend fun otherFunc(db: CustomersDatabase) {
    delay(100) // Why are you doing this? Probably can remove this line.
    val rowId = db.customersDao().getLast()!!.id
    db.customersDao().insertPhone(PhoneNumberEntity(phone = "", customerId = rowId , field = "" ))
}
```

You can call `addNewCustomerAsync()` from a listener/callback in one of your Composable functions, but you cannot call it directly. Really, these kinds of function that interact with a database should be in a ViewModel, so I would remove the `coroutineScope` parameter from `addNewCustomerAsync()` and have it use `viewModelScope`.

Comment: Also, instead of manually creating IDs, I would use `autogenerate`. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44109700/how-to-make-primary-key-as-autoincrement-for-room-persistence-lib

Comment: Composable functions with the Unit return must start with upper case 
also, I need to create ids manually also otherFunc is a composable function so it can't run from a coroutine

Comment: It is forbidden for otherFunc to be Composable because it’s writing to a repo. Likewise since addNewCustomer calls otherFunc, it cannot be Composable either. You need to think reactively instead of imperatively when using Compose.